# laravel Route call loalhost api file on staging server

Tags: laravel, vue.js

laravel route file
`var apiUrl =  "http://myipaddress/api";`

after that i am calling login api that its called localhost path :
`http://localhost:8000/api`

and it gives CORS error as below:

Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myipaddress' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read up on CORS generally: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

To solve your issue, you'd need to configure your webserver to allow that origin, by e.g. using this middleware: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

See the Configuration part of the docs concerning `allowedOrigins`.

Kind regards